# See console.log from React Native app in Xcode when running on device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, react-native

Am building a React Native app and testing on IOS. Have to run it on device as am using voice recognition modules.

My usual debugging method is to use console.log to print out variables as I go along but they are not being displayed in Xcode debugging output area in Xcode 9.4.1.

Current work around is to show my variables on the app in a  component - but this isn't so flexible!